# MySql trigger called when a specific user affect an insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to create a trigger in mysql that executed when a specific user insert a row

i did this but i always been called no matter which user

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER InsertUser AFTER INSERT ON user
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE `username` varchar(20);
        SET `username` = (SELECT CURRENT_USER());
        IF (`username` = 'newuser@localhost') THEN
            INSERT INTO `onp_20170602`.`user_sync` (`User_ID`,`User_Matricule`,`Type_Operation`,`Date_Operation`) VALUES (NEW.ID,NEW.Matricule,'Add',Now());
      END IF;
    END;|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Side note: I would not define username as `VARCHAR(20)`.. the mysql.user columns User and Host are defined much larger. User `VARCHAR(32)` and Host `VARCHAR(60)`

Comment: Wierd so you are saying the INSERT always been executed no matter which user? That should not be possible this trigger code looks correct. You sure this trigger code runs on the MySQL server?

Comment: Yes i'm sure and i test it after it didn't work out for me i tried to save the user name when it called and i found out that every time it been called no matter which user i used to log to mysql the trigger lunched under root user

Comment: @RaymondNijland  i did 20 just for testing i know that it can be much longer but in my condition as you see it's only 17 caracter